# Python enum.Flag with one flag that is used by some others

Tags: python, enums, enum-flags

I would like to define a set of flags (subclassed from `enum.Flag`), with some flags which are defined based on others. This is similar to the white flag in the example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag, but it is not just a combinations of previous flags, but needs its own value too.

My first attempt was:

```
from enum import Flag, auto
class MyFlag(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    DEFAULT = auto()
    FIRST = auto() | DEFAULT
    SECOND = auto() | DEFAULT
    THIRD = auto()
    ANY = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD
```

But this raised an error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'auto' and 'int'`

The working implementation should give:

```
>>> print(bool(MyFlag.FIRST & MyFlag.DEFAULT))
# prints True
>>> print(bool(MyFlag.THIRD & MyFlag.DEFAULT))
# prints False
```

Answer (score 2):

The `auto()` object in `aenum`<sup>1</sup> is much more robust:

```
from aenum import Flag, auto

class MyFlag(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    DEFAULT = auto()
    FIRST = auto() | DEFAULT
    SECOND = auto() | DEFAULT
    THIRD = auto()
    ANY = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(MyFlag)
[
    <MyFlag.NONE: 0>,
    <MyFlag.DEFAULT: 1>,
    <MyFlag.FIRST: 3>,
    <MyFlag.SECOND: 5>,
    <MyFlag.THIRD: 8>,
    <MyFlag.ANY: 15>,
    ]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: That looks exactly like how I imagined the code should be written. I'll check out aenum. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome!! Great job for `aenum`! It actually makes you wonder why `ANY = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD` is not part of `stdlib.enum` by default :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you don't need to do `auto() | DEFAULT`, the rest works fine out of the box:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class MyFlag(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    DEFAULT = auto()
    FIRST = auto()
    SECOND = auto()
    THIRD = auto()
    ANY = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD
```

And we would have

```py
>>> [
...    MyFlag.NONE,
...    MyFlag.DEFAULT,
...    MyFlag.FIRST,
...    MyFlag.SECOND,
...    MyFlag.THIRD,
...    MyFlag.ANY,
...    MyFlag.FIRST | MyFlag.SECOND,
...    MyFlag.FIRST | MyFlag.SECOND | MyFlag.THIRD,
... ]
[<MyFlag.NONE: 0>,
 <MyFlag.DEFAULT: 1>,
 <MyFlag.FIRST: 2>,
 <MyFlag.SECOND: 4>,
 <MyFlag.THIRD: 8>,
 <MyFlag.ANY: 14>,
 <MyFlag.SECOND|FIRST: 6>,
 <MyFlag.ANY: 14>]
```

This works as well with `enum.IntFlag`.

Answer (score -1):

The following works, by defining a hidden member of the `MyFlag` class.

```
from enum import Flag, auto
class MyFlag(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    DEFAULT = auto()
    _FIRST = auto()
    FIRST = _FIRST | DEFAULT
    _SECOND = auto()
    SECOND = _SECOND | DEFAULT
    THIRD = auto()
    ANY = FIRST | SECOND | THIRD
```

Comment: They aren't hidden:  `list(MyFlag)` --> `[<MyFlag.NONE: 0>, <MyFlag.DEFAULT: 1>, <MyFlag._FIRST: 2>, <MyFlag.FIRST: 3>, <MyFlag._SECOND: 4>, <MyFlag.SECOND: 5>, <MyFlag.THIRD: 8>, <MyFlag.ANY: 15>]`